# Shortened Reed-Solomon proving p(D) is primitive

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

Assume we have a shortened $(n=18, k=12, t=3)$ Reed Solomon code in $GF(2^{8})$.Let $\alpha$ be a primitive element of $GF(2^{8})$. Consider the primitive polynomial given by: $p(D) = D^{8} + D^{4} + D^{3} + D^{2} + 1$. Show that $p(D)$ is a primitive polynomial with root $\alpha$ for the field $GF(2^{8})$.

To start of with we've never worked with a shortened RS code. I'm assuming $(n=18, k=12, t=3)$ comes from $(n=255, k=249, t=3)$ where we just removed 237 information bits?

Now I know I could construct a table for every element from 0 to $\alpha^{253}$ using the "primitive polynomial" p(D), and if every element has a different representation we know p(D) was in fact the primitive polynomial but.. Well.. Doing that that many times will take A LOT OF TIME. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: This RS-code has byte size alphabets, so the length of a code block is shortened from 255 **bytes** to 18. Shortening means setting 237 information bytes to zero. A most natural of doing that is to use the same generator polynomial, and set the coefficients of 237 highest degree terms to zero. I guess anothe method can also be described (leading to e.g. systematic encodeing), but that choice does not really concern us here.

Comment: The alternative to reproducing that table of residues of $D^t, t=0,1,\ldots,254$ modulo $p(D)$ is to first prove that $p(D)$ is irreducible. That amounts to checking that it is not divisible by any of the degree $\le 4$ irreducible polynomial (there are only eight of those, so that's quick). After that point you will know that the smallest exponent $t$ such that $p(D)\mid D^t+1$ is a factor of $255=3\cdot5\cdot17$, but is not a factor of $15$. Thus it suffices to show that neither $t=255/3=85$ nor $t=255/5=51$ work. That is undoubtedly fastest to do by the good ol' *square-and-multiply*.

Comment: Mind you, if you are on your way to implementing this on a computer, you might as well go and reproduce that table. While doing that you will also generate a discrete log look-up-table for this field, and you can use that later to do calculations with this field. My initialization routines always commence with the generation of such LUTs.